# I want to print all the input of this string in for loop but it only prints the last input

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop, printf

Help me correcting this code.... *I don't know what extra details should I give so it lets me post*.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char s[34];
    int  a = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("Student %d enter your name: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", s);
    }

   for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("Student %d name is %s\n", i+1, s);
    } 
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only have one `s` variable so you can only ever have one value in it. Maybe you need an array of strings: `char s[4][34];` and read/write `s[i]` in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the same block of memory: `scanf("%s", s);`.

You should have `s` as an array of pointers to `char` i.e. `char *s[4]` in which case you should allocate space for each name using `malloc` and then use `free` to give back all allocated memory to the OS.

Or, you could declare `s` to be `char s[4][34]` and use `s[i]` in your `scanf` and `printf` statements.